# Get the number of images created by ImageMagick from a PDF?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick

I'm using the following command to convert a PDF into a set of images:

```
convert -density 300 test.pdf -quality 100 test.jpg
```

As my `test.pdf` contains 5 pages, it generates the images `test-0.jpg`, `test-1.jpg`, `test-2.jpg`, `test-3.jpg` and `test-4.jpg`. However, as I am doing this programmatically, I do not know how many were generated.

Is there any way ImageMagick can return me the number of images generated as a result of converting the PDF into image(s)?

I'm using NodeJS to run the `imagemagick` package as a wrapper for the above command, but I expect the functionality to be available in ImageMagick itself if anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick command line, you can find the number of pages (images that will be created as follows using a bit of unix.

```
convert -ping image.pdf -format "%n\n" info: | tail -n 1
```

Returns

```
5
```

Without the unix tail, you would get

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any way I can combine that with the PDF to image conversion script I have above?

Comment: I do not know. You can probably do the same with PHP Imagick, but I do not know that API very well.